# Model Relation not updated

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I created a post from an author, and what im doing is fire an event listener when an author reaches a X number of posts, so what im doing is something like:

```php
$author = Author::where('author_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()
$post = new Tip();
$post->author_id = $author->id;
...
$post-save();
```

So now imagine that i already had 5 posts before this previous save, now i should have 6;

But when i call a model method from author:

```php
dd(sizeof($author->posts));
```

It gives me 5, and i can imagine that this is because the post was saved before the instance created from the $author, but i was expecting to create a query when i called "$author->posts" and give me the current results.

Can someone tell me whats wrong, and if Laravel have an approach for these situations besides of creating one new instance after the save and get the posts length?

Comment: You can also reload the relationship: `$author->load('posts');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because somewhere you ran `$author->posts` before the save, the posts 
retrieved and cached until the php script finishes the execution.

to make sure you get the latest changes try execute the query again by this:

`dd(sizeof($author->posts()->get()));`

Comment: Why?   While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is all executed in the same request then an existing $author object may not have knowledge of a new $post if it has been saved in the way you describe.

You could save via [the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method), which will update $author's knowledge of posts, e.g.

```
$author = Author::findOrFail(Auth::id());
$post = new Post(['message' => 'A new post.']);
$author->posts()->save($post);
dd($author->posts()->count());
```